# Is View already a pure component in react native?

Tags: react-native

In React Native, say I have something like

```
var styles = { ... }
export default class App extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{width: this.state.widthA}} />
                <View style={{width: this.state.widthB}} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

when the state `widthA` changes, the render() function is called again. Will the sibling View (widthB) also re-render? Would there be any performance boost to define

```
class PureView extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return <View {...this.props} />
    }
}
```

and replace both Views with PureView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually yes re-render will occur because re-render in react belongs to two things.

`1. The props of the parent is changed.`

`2. The state of a component changed.`

So in your case state of a component is changing that's why your sibling will also re-render because the state of the parent of these two siblings is been changed.

To avoid this, There are two doing this.

`1. Use Pure component`

Pure component looked at previous state and next state and handle your re-render smartly but the pure component is not applicable or useful in every case.

`2. ShouldComponentUpdate`

This method is used for handling re-renders manually like as in your case you don't want to re-render your second sibling so you can return false according to your prop in the lifecycle method of your sibling so this component will not re-render by this change.

`The View is just a UI container re-rendering depends on component props or state, So View can't control the re-render of a component`.